# MS Access convert rows to columns using pivot

Tags: ms-access, pivot, transform

I have a table with ~6500 products and images in which each product can have several jpg files:

```
ID_product      product       product_photo  ordering
1               Product A     a1234.jpg      1
2               Product B     x5678.jpg      0
3               Product A     b1234.jpg      0
4               Product B     y5678.jpg      1
5               Product B     z5678.jpg      2
6               Product C     e4455.jpg      1
7               Product C     f4455.jpg      0
8               Product C     g4455.jpg      2
```

So I created a query in MS ACCESS:

```
TRANSFORM First([table1].product_photo) AS product
SELECT [table1].ID_product, First([table1].product) AS products
FROM [table1]
GROUP BY [table1].ID_product
PIVOT [table1].product_photo;
```

The result of the query:

```
ID_product  product         a1234_jpg   b1234_jpg   e4455_jpg   f4455_jpg   g4455_jpg   x5678_jpg   y5678_jpg   z5678_jpg
1           Product A       a1234.jpg   b1234.jpg                       
2           Product B                                                                   x5678.jpg   y5678.jpg   z5678.jpg
3           Product C                               e4455.jpg   f4455.jpg   g4455.jpg
```

I would like to change the table in such a way that the images are in columns:

```
ID_product      product             image_1    image_2     image_3
1               Product A           a1234.jpg  b1234.jpg
2               Product B           x5678.jpg  y5678.jpg   z5678.jpg
3               Product C           e4455.jpg  f4455.jpg   g4455.jpg
```

How to expand the query to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Because the Pivot works on the *value* of the column rather than its *name*, you are out of luck. This is the problem with pivoting - it's fairly limited in its flexibility.

At this point, you usually revert to code. For example, you could build the result set in VBA in an array of arrays of variant.

Or, you could use VBA to count the maximum number of columns for any product, create a temp table with appropriately named columns, and insert the values into the appropriate rows.

Either way, this is really a *UI* issue of sexy display to the user, rather than handing off data from one query to the next, which is what SQL is designed for.